# Hibernate validator doesn't use properties file.

Tags: java, hibernate, internationalization, hibernate-validator

I have implemented a bean with hibernate and hibernate validation. This is the field I am testing on.

```
@NotBlank(message ="test.test" )
private String test;
```

I have a file

> messages.properties

and

```
 messages_en.properties
```

that I use. Spring.message tags work so the files can be found and are used in the system elsewhere. I get "test.test" as my validation error when I try to store an object with that field empty and not error message in messages.properties. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i was missing this in my configuration. Also message="{test.test}" was necessary.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator" />   

<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageInterpolator">
        <bean class="org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator">
            <constructor-arg index="0">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="messageSource" />
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try like this by enclosing key name with curly braces. This syntax is different than Java from the localization files. It's followed with Spring/Hibernate Validation thru Validation API.

`@NotBlank(message="{test.test}")
private String test;`

Comment: Thanks. But then it uses that String instead.

Answer (score 0):

Only below worked for me:

1. Create ValidationMessages.properties in "resources" directory of maven project with the below message property:

   ```
   app.validation.notempty.msg=must be populated
   ```
2. Then, in dto class:

   ```
   @NotEmpty(message = "{app.validation.notempty.msg}")
   private String fieldName;
   ```
3. Fially validate as shown below. Please note **I found provider HibernateValidator.class is mandatory** to take the values from .properties file.

   ```
   ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byProvider( 
   HibernateValidator.class )
           .configure()
           .buildValidatorFactory();
   Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
   ```

Hope this helps someone.